# Como integrar o font awesome no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estou a utilizar o font awesome no laravel junto com bootstrap, até então utilizava via Link, tanto css quanto js.

Hoje estou migrando para controle via npm, porém instalo e o icone não aparece. Sabem me dizer o que poderia ser?

```html
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar por palavra-chave" autofocus aria-describedby="input_search" >
   <div class="input-group-append">
     <span class="input-group-text p-l-r-40" id="input_search" >
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
     </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Ao executar "npm install" 
+ font-awesome@4.7.0

Comment: você está fazendo algo front-end ou back-end ?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Desculpe, não entendi a sua pergunta.

Comment: Laravel que você está desenvolvendo? se sim é back end ... então precisa instalar na sua pasta `public` e não no pacote do npm, ou é Front End que você está programando em conjunto com BackEnd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mesmo instalando via NPM, você ainda precisa referenciar os arquivos em seu projeto. O próprio Font Awesome tem em sua [documentação](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers) uma referência de como utilizar os ícones usando um gerenciador de pacotes.

[Essa questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406538/how-to-use-font-awesome-icons-from-node-modules) tem uma resposta bem mais compreensiva, mas está em inglês. De qualquer forma, você precisará referenciar o arquivo do font-awesome de alguma forma, como por exemplo:

```
@import url('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

[Esse link](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/npm/fontawesome-npm-installation-and-setup/) também contém um tutorial bem explicativo e ainda mais compreensivo, juntamente com a sua [versão mais recente](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/npm/fontawesome-5-pro-npm-and-webpack-guide/) (ambos em inglês).

Answer (score 2):

Vou apenas dizer o que eu fiz caso mais alguem tenha chegado até este ponto...

executei via npm:

> npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free

Em seguida fui em:

> resources/sass/app.scss

E inseri o seguinte bloco de código:

> ```
> //FontAwesome
> @import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
> @import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
> @import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
> @import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
> ```

E executei

> npm run dev

Dei como reposta correta ao nosso amigo pois a resposta dele me levou até esta solução, então seria o mais justo!